# Repeating an event like in iphone reminder app

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

In iPhone reminder app you can set a calendar event to repeat, say, every three days after a specified date, until reaching another specified date. I am starting to create an app that should have a feature like that. My first attempt was to use local notifications, but I have not seen a way to program a trigger using date components to do that. Am I overlooking something about local notifications or date components, or are there other ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` And `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`? 
You probably have to combine the two. Use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` for the initial event at a certain date and then `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` for repeating the event.

Comment: @ Robin Bork, yes I'm using `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`, but as far as I can see, it offers no way to implement that sort of trigger. As for `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`, it is not useful for that purpose for itself, and I don't see how to combine it with  `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` when creating the trigger. Thanks for you comment anyway.